# The Connection is Successful but nogetting the data into website mysql

Tags: php, mysql

We are Trying to Connect php & mysql we got connection successful but we are not receiving the data any ideas please guide

Also we are using mysql and php

```
The Connection is Successful but nogetting the data into website

enter code here`Please let me know who to correct it<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome to PDM</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<centre>
Good For Checking The Prices
</centre>
<?php>` 


    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "wikiacwj_price";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "wikiacwj_price";

    mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Please Try Again");
    mysql_select_db("wikiacwj_price") or die ("no data");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price_comparsion where product_name='ok'");

    //write the results

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)); {
    echo $row['product_name'];}

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Dialect:  One more reason not to use the <center> tag.

Answer (score 2):

The Semicolon immediately after your while statement telling the while loop to do ... nothing :)

```
...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  echo $row['product_name'];
}
...
```

shoud do the trick.

Comment: Notable to get you please help with echo code for the display in the website